# Setting up Mysql on EC2 (ubuntu). Having issue with XFS

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-ec2

I have been following the directions on setting up a MySql database on EC2 here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

I got a problem when I run:

```
$ sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdh
Cannot stat /dev/sdh: No such file or directory
```

What can it be?

Edit: 
I ran the following based on @karudzo advice

```
$ cd /dev
$ sudo /sbin/MAKEDEV sdh
$ sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdh
mkfs.xfs: cannot open /dev/sdh: No such device or address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that /dev/sdh doesn't exist yet.  Try this:  http://getsatisfaction.com/cohesiveft/topics/attaching_a_ebs_volume_to_ec2_instance_at_dev_sdh_doesnt_appear_to_attach

Comment: You need to attach the EBS volume in the AWS control panel then.  Stop the server, do that first and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create ad-hoc devices for your instances. In the Amazon console you'll need to:

1) Create an EBS volume

2) Attach that volume to your instance at device location /dev/sdh

Then you'll be able to run mkfs.xfs on the block device